# ValueError: shape mismatch: objects cannot be broadcast to a single shape Python Error

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib

## Code

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = pd.read_csv("../Heart_Disease_Prediction.csv")
boy = data[data.Sex == 1]
girl = data[data.Sex == 0]

plt.figure("Heart Disease", figsize=(8, 5))
plt.title("Cholesterol Levels for Heart Diseases for Age Groups", size=11)
plt.xlabel("Age", size=11)
plt.ylabel("Cholesterol Level", size=11)
plt.axis([28, 80, 0, 400])
plt.grid(color="k", linewidth=0.5, linestyle="dotted")

x_age = np.arange(len(data.Age))
width = 0.25

plt.bar(x_age - width, boy.Cholesterol, color="#444444", label="Boy")
plt.bar(x_age + width, girl.Cholesterol, color="tab:blue", label="Girl")

plt.xticks(ticks=x_age, labels=data.Age)
plt.legend(prop={"size": 10}, loc="upper left")
plt.show()
```

## Question

I am using these lines of code but it keeps giving me a "ValueError: shape mismatch: objects cannot be broadcast to a single shape" error. Any way to fix this?

Comment: Hi @heman it would be better if you provide a [minimum reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), as we don't have access to the data. It would also help if you provide the full traceback/error message. The error might related to the different lengths of `x_age` and `boy.Cholesterol` (or `girl.Cholesterol`).

Answer (score 0):

The following link must help you
https://cumsum.wordpress.com/2020/08/30/matplotlib-valueerror-shape-mismatch-objects-cannot-be-broadcast-to-a-single-shape/

The reason being that when plotting you always expect to have the x coordinate and y coordinate to come in pairs. If they don’t have the same length, matplotlib can’t figure out how to plot it.

So when you get this error, double check your input to the plot functions and make sure they are what you meant them to be.